# Wordpress breaks jQuery background animation script

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I get the error shown below (73TypeError) on a small background animation script when included in the header of a Wordpress theme, which breaks the script.  I don't see any error when the script is included on non-Wordpress page:

[image]

Here is the script:

```
$(function() {
   $(".bottom").hover( function () {
      $(this).animate( {
         backgroundPosition : '0px 35px'}
      , 300); }
   , function () {
      $(this).animate( {
         backgroundPosition : '0px 0px'}
      , 600); }
   ); 
   }
);
```

Could someone advise at what is causing this error?

Thanks,

Nick

Comment: that's because jQuery is not loaded. read this [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)

Comment: oh, jQuery was showing up in the list of scripts on the page so I presumed it was included.  I added `<?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>` above `wp_head();` in the header.php file for my child theme and now I get the error `TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$')` on the penultimate line of the above script

Comment: click on the loaded jQuery file on the list and check to see it's loaded correctly.

Comment: @undefined jQuery is loaded correctly, even without adding `<?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>` So now I need to work out how to include the no conflict script below and the original backgroundPosition.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fist off in wordpress, jQuery should be loaded with no-COnflict. So in this case your file should be;

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(function() {
   $j(".bottom").hover( function () {
      $j(this).animate( {
         backgroundPosition : '0px 35px'}
      , 300); }
   , function () {
      $j(this).animate( {
         backgroundPosition : '0px 0px'}
      , 600); }
   ); 
   }
);
```

and secondly, like undefined mentioned, you need to load your jQuery using `wp-enqueue-script();`

To accomplish this, for best practices, place your jQuery on a separate file. call it for example bganimation.js

now to load that js file in wordpress, use wp-enqueue-script(); like this.

```
function this_is_jquery_example(){
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );;
wp_enqueue_script('myscript', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) .' bganimation.js');

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','this_is_jquery_example');
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful.  As mentioned above in my comment to undefined, I thought jQuery was included.  I have followed your instructions, and the path to the bganimation.js that I created isn't getting set correctly: `http://soteriabrighton.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/home/nickputm/public_html/soteriabrighton.co.uk/wp-content/themes/bp-soteria/bganimation.js?ver=3.4`

Comment: Are you trying to include this directly into a theme or you are creating a plugin?

Comment: I created a separate file called bganimation.js and put it in the wp-content/plugins folder

Comment: oh! then the code above would not be applicable. that was for a plugin.

Comment: Mmmh, I'm a little confused.  I have the original backgroundPosition.js and then the script above, which is now saved in a separate file called bganimation.js.  I could combine the two scripts.  Would this then constitute a plugin that would work with your code?  Sorry for being rather slow on this one.

Comment: Thanks.  I eventually got this working using a function to include backgroundPosition.js, loading the script above in no conflict mode, as per you answer, using the **scripts n styles** plugin, and I now have it working.  It turns out that jQuery was included as standard with the Buddypress standard theme